# Use a loop on a dataframe by taking a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to pandas and python. Here I have a data-frame,

```
DID   feature
0      1
0      1
0      2
0      22
0      22
0      33
1      11 
1      13 
1      14
1       2
1      33
2      1
2      22
2      33 
2      13
2      14
```

In this dataframe there are two columns. `DID` is a document Id and and feature is the feature of that .
Now, I am trying to use a for loop here on the basis of the document ID's ..

I am trying to call a fucntion inside a loop which will have the data of that `DID` only , like the features of that DID only.

so

```
for i in df1 :
   call_process ["Here only the values of i"] (i is the document ID , which will be first 0).
call_process[df1['feature'].values]
```

like this ?

Is there any way to do this ?

expected output is like ,

while calling a method it should have the data of that document ID only.

```
call_process([1,1,2,22,22,33])
```

Comment: what is your expected output? looks like you might need `groupby` instead of a for loop , but we would need more details on the logic and your expected output.

Comment: I have just updated the output

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your purpose, but you may do it with for-loop on  `groupby` object.

```
for _, g in df1.groupby('DID'):
    call_process(g['feature'].values)
```

Comment: ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series

Comment: do you use `values` or `values()` ?

Comment: (g['PredictedFeature'].values) has worked.. but do I need to convert it in the list() ?

Comment: No. I just make it to list as an extra cautious. As long as numpy array works, don't convert it to list :)

Comment: could  u please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991053/create-a-sub-columns-in-the-dataframe-using-a-another-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment104233258_58991053

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, here is a simple function to get you the features for a DID:

```
def get_features(did):

    feats = [] #to load the matching features

    for d,idx in zip(df['DID'],range(len(df))): #get DID and index of DID

        if d == did:
            feats.append(df['feature'][idx])

    return feats #return the features in a list
```

Then you call the function with did value you want, suppose it is DID 0:

```
   get_features(0)
```

And it returns:

```
   [1, 1, 2, 22, 22, 33]
```