# Create a sub columns in the dataframe using a another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am new to the python and pandas. Here, I have a following dataframe .

```
did           features   offset   word   JAPE_feature  manual_feature 
0             200         0        aa      200          200 
0             200         11       bf      200          200
0             200         12       vf      100          100
0             100         13       rw      2200         2200
0             100         14       asd     2600         100 
0             2200        16       dsdd    2200         2200
0             2600        18       wd      2200         2600 
0             2600        20       wsw     2600         2600 
0             4600        21        sd     4600         4600
```

Now , I have an array which has all the feature values which can appear for that id.

```
feat = [100,200,2200,2600,156,162,4600,100]
```

Now, I am trying to create a dataframe whic will look like,

```
id                    Features 
           100   200   2200   2600  156   162    4600  100
0           0     1      0     0     0     0      0     0
1           0     1      0     0     0     0      0     0
2           0     1      0     0     0     0      0     0
3           0     1      0     0     0     0      0     0
4           1     0      0     0     0     0      0     0
5           1     0      0     0     0     0      0     0
7           0     0      1     0     0     0      0     0
8           0     0      0     1     0     0      0     0
9           0     0      0     1     0     0      0     0
10          0     0      0     0     0     0      1     0
```

so, while doing comparision ,

```
feature_manual
     1 
     1  
     0 
     0
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1

Here compairing the features and the manual_feature columns. if values are same then 1 or else 0. so 200 and 200 for 0 is same in both so 1
```

So, this is the expected output. Here I am trying to add the value 1 for that feature in the new csv and for other 0.

```
So, it is by row by row.
```

So, If we check in the first row the feature is 200 so there is 1 at 200 and others are 0.

can any one help me with this ?

what I tried is

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['features'],feat)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=mux)
```

SO, Here creatig subcolumns but removing all other values . can any one help me ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually I tried using the for loop and creating the subcolumns.. But it was not working.

Comment: Please include that code and show the output you get from it, that makes it much easier for people to answer your question

Comment: added what I tried please check

Answer (score 2):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
feat = [100,200,2200,2600,156,162,4600,100]
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.pop('features')).reindex(feat, axis=1, fill_value=0))
print (df)
   id  100  200  2200  2600  156  162  4600  100
0   0    0    1     0     0    0    0     0    0
1   1    0    1     0     0    0    0     0    0
2   2    0    1     0     0    0    0     0    0
3   4    1    0     0     0    0    0     0    1
4   5    1    0     0     0    0    0     0    1
5   7    0    0     1     0    0    0     0    0
6   8    0    0     0     1    0    0     0    0
7   9    0    0     0     1    0    0     0    0
8  10    0    0     0     0    0    0     1    0
```

If need `MultiIndex` only pass `mux` to `reindex`, but also convert `id` column to `index`:

```
feat = [100,200,2200,2600,156,162,4600,100]
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['features'],feat])

df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id')['features']).reindex(mux, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (df)
   features                                   
       100  200  2200 2600 156  162  4600 100 
id                                            
0         0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1         0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2         0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4         0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
5         0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
7         0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
8         0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
9         0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
10        0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

EDIT:

```
cols = ['features', 'JAPE_feature', 'manual_feature']

df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=cols)
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_',1, expand=True)
print (df)
  did offset  word features                    JAPE_feature                \
  NaN    NaN   NaN      100 200 2200 2600 4600          100 200 2200 2600   
0   0      0    aa        0   1    0    0    0            0   1    0    0   
1   0     11    bf        0   1    0    0    0            0   1    0    0   
2   0     12    vf        0   1    0    0    0            1   0    0    0   
3   0     13    rw        1   0    0    0    0            0   0    1    0   
4   0     14   asd        1   0    0    0    0            0   0    0    1   
5   0     16  dsdd        0   0    1    0    0            0   0    1    0   
6   0     18    wd        0   0    0    1    0            0   0    1    0   
7   0     20   wsw        0   0    0    1    0            0   0    0    1   
8   0     21    sd        0   0    0    0    1            0   0    0    0   

       manual_feature                     
  4600            100 200 2200 2600 4600  
0    0              0   1    0    0    0  
1    0              0   1    0    0    0  
2    0              1   0    0    0    0  
3    0              0   0    1    0    0  
4    0              1   0    0    0    0  
5    0              0   0    1    0    0  
6    0              0   0    0    1    0  
7    0              0   0    0    1    0  
8    1              0   0    0    0    1
```

If want avoid missing values in `MultIndex` in columns for columns with no `MultiIndex`:

```
cols = ['features', 'JAPE_feature', 'manual_feature']
df = df.set_index(df.columns.difference(cols).tolist())

df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=cols)
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_',1, expand=True)
print (df)
                features                    JAPE_feature                     \
                     100 200 2200 2600 4600          100 200 2200 2600 4600   
did offset word                                                               
0   0      aa          0   1    0    0    0            0   1    0    0    0   
    11     bf          0   1    0    0    0            0   1    0    0    0   
    12     vf          0   1    0    0    0            1   0    0    0    0   
    13     rw          1   0    0    0    0            0   0    1    0    0   
    14     asd         1   0    0    0    0            0   0    0    1    0   
    16     dsdd        0   0    1    0    0            0   0    1    0    0   
    18     wd          0   0    0    1    0            0   0    1    0    0   
    20     wsw         0   0    0    1    0            0   0    0    1    0   
    21     sd          0   0    0    0    1            0   0    0    0    1   

                manual_feature                     
                           100 200 2200 2600 4600  
did offset word                                    
0   0      aa                0   1    0    0    0  
    11     bf                0   1    0    0    0  
    12     vf                1   0    0    0    0  
    13     rw                0   0    1    0    0  
    14     asd               1   0    0    0    0  
    16     dsdd              0   0    1    0    0  
    18     wd                0   0    0    1    0  
    20     wsw               0   0    0    1    0  
    21     sd                0   0    0    0    1
```

EDIT:

If want compare some column from list by `manual_feature` column use [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with converting to integers:

```
cols = ['JAPE_feature', 'features']
df1 = df[cols].eq(df['manual_feature'], axis=0).astype(int)
print (df1)
   JAPE_feature  features
0             1         1
1             1         1
2             1         0
3             1         0
4             0         1
5             1         1
6             0         1
7             1         1
8             1         1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203005/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-create-a-sub-columns-in-the-dataframe-using-a-an).

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - But is is only display problem, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961320/set-index-not-indexing-in-pandas/35961699#35961699)

Comment: mistake by me I edited the answer instead of adding that information in the question sorry for that

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - So you want display values? Because if write to file, then values for first level of MultiIndex are repeated correctly.

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - OK, so use `with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df1)` solution from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961320/set-index-not-indexing-in-pandas/35961699#35961699)

Comment: actually, If I want to have the compare result in the same df then ?

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - OK, I have one idea. For each new question please create new question in SO, because in this answer are 5 solutions and do you need another ? In SO is best one question, one answer (edit in question only if really necessary, else not).

Comment: I tried that but not working with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203010/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ganesh-kaspate).

Comment: Hey only one thing was unclear to me is . I have a
feat_filter = [100,156,160,162,200,256,262,2000,2200,2600,2900,3600,4600,300]
which is the number of sub-columns for the three columns .but here with this code all these are not getting added only those which are present in the input csv are getting added  .. In the answer also the same thing

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for your solutions. As, I am getting an error which is ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity  . After I try to use the mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([cols,feat_filter])
read_one_csv = read_one_csv.reindex(mux, axis=1)

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - yop, give me some time.

Comment: Hey,After doing this , Actually was in some emergency, but after applying the latest change MANUAL_PREDICTEDFEATURE for this column it is not working giving all values as 0 . and the datatype is unsigned int8  the column values I am  getting are 2200.0

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - if not working with real data problem is in data, unfortunately without data with problem I dont know what should be problem.

Comment: No nO, actually your soln is great.. the only thing is that when I did df.columns that time the columns of manaual_predicted are getting values as 2200.0, 200.0,2100.0 and for others they are like 2200,200,2100.. so I am a bit confused there, may be because of that all are getting added as 0 in that manual_predictded

Comment: @jezrael  thanks for your help.. This works perfectly fine. Just one thing, I tried to change the sequence of columns but here the other columns like did,offset,word are not coming when I did output.columns only JAPE,MANAUL,RFC, and their subs like 200,2100 are coming. I am trying to attach the jape_error and rfc_error at last . so

Comment: @jezrael after using with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False): print (df1)   works for printing the df but on saving it does not show the same way

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - sorry, not understand.

Comment: So, I used the  pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):  so that it should give me each value in  that column even if it is repeating as previously it was giving me a value and others empty because all were same.. so I used this solution the after doing this if I print the df then it works.like it shows all data.. but when I save the data in xlsx format then it does not show values for every row.. only which are unique

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - What is reason for use `pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False)` ?

Comment: Hey in out chat I have just sent u an image. so there only one 0 is getting added as  and not for all 0 same for jape_error

Comment: @jezrael can you please help a bit about why the elements are not getting repeated in the xlsx  file. ? even after using pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False)

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - hmmm, but `pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False)` is only for display values, data are not changed in dataframe, so it is expected.

Comment: yeah that is what I am also getting. Using this solution , actually,  I have sent you a  image in chat which has the data it is getting in xlsx file.

Comment: @jezrael It retuns the proper data in the dataframe , but once I save it to xlsx format it applies that

Comment: One more thing if I try to print the column names in the df then it gives me only the multindex column names and not the other ones

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - Unfortunately not idea.

Answer (score 0):

Less fancy solution, but maybe easier to understand:

First of all put the features that will decide which feature you choose on each row in a list called for example `list_features`.

Then:

```
# List all the features possible and create an empty df
feat = [100,200,2200,2600,156,162,4600,100]
df_final= pd.DataFrame({x:[] for x in feat})

# Fill the df little by little
for x in list_features:
    df_final = df_final.append({y:1 if x==y else 0 for y in feat }, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

These types of problems can be solved in many ways. But here I am using simple way to solve it. Creating df with those features list as a column names and the using some comparison logic to update df with 0 and 1. You can use some other logic to avoid use of for loops.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id':[0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10],
'features':[200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 100, 2200, 2600, 2600, 4600]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

features_list = [100,200,2200,2600,156,162,4600]
id_list = df1.id.to_list()

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=features_list)
list2 = list()

for i in id_list:
    list1 = list()
    for k in df2.columns:
        if df1[df1.id == i].features.iloc[0] == k:
            list1.append(1)
        else:
            list1.append(0)
    list2.append(list1)

for i in range (0,len(list2)):
    df2.loc[i] = list2[i]

df2.insert(0, "id", id_list)   

>>>(df2)
   id 100 200 2200 2600 156 162 4600
0   0   0   1    0    0   0   0    0
1   1   0   1    0    0   0   0    0
2   2   0   1    0    0   0   0    0
3   3   0   1    0    0   0   0    0
4   4   1   0    0    0   0   0    0
5   5   1   0    0    0   0   0    0
6   7   0   0    1    0   0   0    0
7   8   0   0    0    1   0   0    0
8   9   0   0    0    1   0   0    0
9  10   0   0    0    0   0   0    1
```